# django database structure for a gym members workout management

Tags: python, django, django-models, admin

i would like to develop a django management app for a small gym.

we have a list of members

each member could have 1 or more card

each card could have 1 or more workout

each workout could have 1 or more exercise

each exercise has the following fields:

exercise name (can be choose from a list of exercise names),
series number (can be choose from a list of series),
repetition number (can be choose from a list of repetition),
execution mode (can be choose from a list of executions),
rest time (can be choose from a list of executions).

Here is my possibile implementation of models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Member(models.Model):

    #Member data
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    #Contact
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    #Body
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    weigth = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    #Trainer notes
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True, 'is_superuser': False}, blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True)

    #Registration status
    registration = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


    card = models.OneToOneField('Card')


    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.surname, self.name)




class Card(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField()

    #Card status
    card_creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    card_expiration = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    workout = models.ForeignKey('Workout')

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.number)





class Workout(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField()
    exercise = models.ForeignKey('Exercise')

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.number)    




class Exercise(models.Model):

    name = models.ForeignKey('Name')
    series = models.ForeignKey('Serie')
    repetitions = models.ForeignKey('Repetition')
    executions = models.ForeignKey('Execution', blank=True, null=True)
    rest = models.ForeignKey('Rest')

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name) 





class Name(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name) 





class Serie(models.Model):

    serie = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.serie)     





class Repetition(models.Model):

    repetition = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.repetition) 




class Execution(models.Model):

    execution = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.execution)     



class Rest(models.Model):

    rest = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.rest)
```

I'm not sure if this works as described. Could you please suggest a possible implementation? 
At the end I would like to have only one view with all data: member, card, workout... so the staff user can modify the user and the linked workout card) is it possible with admin.py or do I need a custom admin?

Comment: did you try out your implementation?

Comment: yes but Im not sure about and the admin interface is not usable because it's not possible to have nested inlines

Answer (score 2):

That looks pretty good, and like Samidh T said in the comments you should open up a dev server with sqlite and play around with it. See what's working what's not. That's the best thing you could do.

However, since you asked, here are a couple notes to bear in mind:

- `"each member could have 1 or more card"` -  Then why is you card field in Memeber a OneToOne? Wouldn't it make more sense to do a ForeignKey (essentially a ManyToOne) field for Card linking it to member?
- `"each card could have 1 or more workout"` - If you have a ForeignKey from card to workout, then you are actually doing the opposite of what you described, you're doing a Many (cards) for One (workout). But maybe this is what you want? Or maybe you actually want it to be a ManyToManyField? Because each workout probably has different cards and vice-versa. I really can't tell what's the best fit here, but it's something you might want to think over.
- `"each workout could have 1 or more exercise"` Same as with the point before.
- I see that every field in your exercise is a ForeingKey. Now again - this is isn't a bad choice or idea, but you should consider what this entails, and consider replacing it with a ManyToMany or, if one of the fields is a static list (i.e. you have a limited list of available names that you know won't change in the future drastically) then you can use a CharField with option `choices=`.

I can't exactly tell you "this is bad", "this is good", it is a very project-subjective thing, but I hope my few tips helped you in some way. In the end, it all boils down to what you need. If you find yourself confused, I suggest reading a little about table relationships in SQL and how they work.

Django is fantastic for realizing complex relationships, but using it without learning a little bit SQL before can be confusing sometimes because you only see the end result and hardly ever look at the tables themselves.

Comment: I played with this I saw that I made some errors as you noticed. I corrected them and now it works quite like I imagined but unfortunately amin interface is not as powerful as I would like.. I would like to have complete control of each card from one single view but with all this relations I can only modify one table at time.. do I need to code a custom back end?

Comment: Try reading the docs about customizing admin site, there are a lot of features for dealing with table relationships (Inlines and such). But bear in mind that since it is uber-generic, it is pretty limited. However, it's also surprisingly easy to mimick on your own, so yeah, if you want specifics build your own views (and don't use generic views!! I mean, not until you're comfortable without them. They are sandtrap for beginners)

Comment: you can search for apps which allow for multiple inlines - there are some around but I did not try any, yet, therefore I don't want to point to a specific one.